# How to retrieve values from the result returned from Gremlin Server

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to retrieve the values of result returned from Gremlin Server into variables in my Java Program but I can only retrieve the value first property (name) but not the others?! Can someone please help?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
        g.addV("person").property("name", "John Cole", "age", 26, "gender", "Male").next();
        g.addV("person").property("name", "Kate Cole", "age", 23, "gender", "Female").next();
        g.addV("person").property("name", "Mary Cole", "age", 18, "gender", "Female").next();
        g.addV("person").property("name", "Andrew Cole", "age", 23, "gender", "Male").next();
        g.addV("person").property("name", "Jackson Cole", "age", 19, "gender", "Male").next();
        g.addV("person").property("name", "Paul Cole", "age", 23, "gender", "Male").next();
        g.addV("person").property("name", "Thomas Cole", "age", 18, "gender", "Male").next();


        List<Map<Object, Object>> people = g.V().hasLabel("person").valueMap().toList();
        for (Map<Object, Object> p : people)
        {
            ArrayList name = (ArrayList) p.get("name");
            ArrayList age = (ArrayList) p.get("age");
            ArrayList gender = (ArrayList) p.get("gender");
            String personDetails = String.format("name: %s, age: %s, gender: %s", name.get(0), age.get(0), gender.get(0));
            System.out.println(personDetails);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working now. I figured out that i made 2 mistakes. First, in the data input and the second in the looping code. I edited the code as follows:

```
g.addV("person").property(T.id, 1).property("name", "John Cole").property("age", 18).property("gender", "Male").next(); 

        List<Map<Object, Object>> people = g.V().hasLabel("person").valueMap().toList();
        for (Map<Object, Object> p : people)
        {
            for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> pDetails : p.entrySet())
            {
                String key = pDetails.getKey().toString();
                String val = pDetails.getValue().toString();
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }
```